# 4X + 2 = 0 in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

i want to solve this equation (4X + 2 = 0) using TensorFlow, i have two questions **about this code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf


x = tf.Variable(0.0)


for i in range(10000):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y = 4 * x + 2
        loss = tf.square(y)
        gradient=tape.gradient(loss,[x])
        tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01).apply_gradients(zip(gradient,[x]))
print(x.numpy())
```

**my first question is :**

why if i declare the equation and its loss function outside the for loop it will lead to an error

```
y = 4 * x + 2
loss = tf.square(y)
```

i mean those variable every iteration will initiate a new address in the memory, so i wanted to put them away of for loop.

**the second question is:**

why should i make the cost function (4X + 2 )^2, then i differentiate the equation again?

Comment: Asking and deleteing the same question multiple times can block you on Stackexchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805913/4x-2-0-in-tensorflow?noredirect=1#comment114580608_64805913 Usually you should try to improve your question.

Comment: i deleted that one!
why you tread me badly?

Comment: I'm not treating you badly. I'm warning you about the system here. People are blocked for some days doing this to often.

Comment: i deleted that one before asking again

Comment: Yes, and exactly that should be avoided. That's not wanted here.

Comment: sorry, i don't know this rule.
what should i do now? @ThomasSablik

Comment: I just informed you about a rule and the consequences of breaking it to often. Breaking it occasionally is not a problem. You have nothing to do now and everything is okay with this question. Just wait for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*On StackOverflow, it is better to ask only one question in a post. In this answer, I will look at your first question. Feel free to ask another question for the second one. I'll edit this answer and remove that part once you have edited your question*

> why if I declare the equation and its loss function outside the for loop it will lead to an error

Since TF2, the default design of tensorflow is eager execution. It means that coding with tensorflow is close to how you would develop in native python.
If we write this tensorflow code in  native python, we would have :

```
learning_rate = 0.01
x = 0.0
training_steps = 100
for _ in range(training_steps):
    # We calculate Y with the current value of X
    y = 4*x + 2
    # we calculate the mean squared error
    error = (y-0)**2
    # We calculate the gradient. 
    # In TF, this is done with a call to tape.gradient
    # dy = 4 * dx
    gradient = 4 * error
    # We correct x with the new gradient. 
    # In TF this is done by calling the optimizer
    x = x - (learning_rate*gradient)
print(x)
# this code results in x=-0.4853790481319223. Not bad!
```

In this native python code, it is clear why we have to recalculate the value of `y` in the loop: as we are changing the value of `x`, we need to update the value of `y` as well! This behaviour is a bit hidden under TF abstractions, but I hope that it is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

> why if i declare the equation and its loss function outside the for
> loop it will lead to an error

I think you are asking specifically about your loop but you can declare the function like this.

```
@tf.function
def f(x):
    Y = 4 * x + 2
    Y = tf.square(Y)
    return Y

x = tf.Variable(0.0)

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)


loss_fn = lambda: f(x)
var_list = [x]

for _ in range(10000):
    opt.minimize(loss_fn, var_list)

print(x.numpy())
```

> -0.49999997